# want to hide some field of object on the basis of key that are being mapped to json

Tags: java, json

I have a User class that I want to map to JSON using Jackson.

```
 private String name;
 private String value;
 private String defaultValue;

Response :

[ {
"name" : "admin.mail.server.ip",
"value" : "smtp.gmail.com"
}, {
"name" : "admin.mail.server.port",
"value" : "587"
}, {
"name" : "admin.mail.server.username",
 "value" : "tdev123456@gmail.com"
}, {
"name" : "admin.mail.server.password",
"value" : "[ffDmpve$2"
}, {
"name" : "admin.mail.smtp.starttls.enable",
"value" : "true"
}, {
 "name" : "admin.mail.smtp.auth",
"value" : "true"
 } ]
```

i want to remove only this value from response -  "value" : "[ffDmpve$2" and not others.

I want to make changes from server side and not client side

Comment: You need to use custom serializer on this field. see http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization

Comment: I want to make changes from server side and not client side

Comment: And you will do it. I passed you link for Jackson Serializer